# Generate Critical css on codeigniter project

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, critical-css

This question is more theoretical than pratical. I need to generate a critical path for css in a site. I read a tutorial on this tool: https://github.com/addyosmani/critical, and i report the basic example here:

```
critical.generate({
    base: 'test/',
    src: 'index.html',
    dest: 'styles/main.css',
    width: 1300,
    height: 900
});
```

In my case i have this codeigniter structure:

```
application
-config
--config.php
--routes.php
--...
-controllers
--Matching.php
--...
-views
--home_matching.php
--page_about.php
--page_contact.php
--...
out
-bundle.min.css //this is the minified css visible in all views
```

routes.php about home page, page about and page contacts are:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Matching';
$route['about'] = 'Matching/about';
$route['contact-us'] = 'Matching/contactus';
```

The listing of methods in the Matching controller is the following:

```
class Matching extends CI_Controller{


public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('home_matching.php');
  }

  function about()
  {
    $this->load->view('page_about.php');
  }

  function contactus()
  {
    $this->load->view('page_contact.php');
  }
```

There is a way to generate a critical css with this structure?